# Trying to process a message received in Bytes using google Protobuf, but sometimes getting "Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag"

Tags: protocol-buffers

We are processing messages received from a Queue, which is in `byte[]`. And processing them using `google Protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar` calling `mergeFrom` of the `com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage`, which in turn is calling `com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream`.

Sometimes, the messages are successfully processed, but sometimes throwing `InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag()`.

I understand that "Groups in protobuf are written as a start/end numeric pair", But as we are receiving the messages in `byte[]`, how can we make sure what are the start and end tags and which end group tag not matched with what expected Tag?

Sometimes, the same message get processed successfully on a local windows machine, but the same message fails on a Linux box.

```
Message.Builder builder = getMessageBuilder(messageType);
ExtensionRegistry registry = ExtensionRegistry.newInstance();
Message parsedMessage = builder.mergeFrom(message, registry).build();`
```

- message is a byte[].
- The 3rd line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Please [apply the appropriate tags to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). For example, is this [tag:java] ?

Comment: This is a Java Program.